# Agrupar valores repetidos de instrução sql de preenchimento de DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou pegando informações de uma tabela e preenchendo um `DropDownList`, mas tenho muitas informações repetidas e gostaria de agrupar os valores para que não se repitam no `DropDownList`.

Exemplo de informações que estou capturando.

```
Cidade1

Cidade2

Cidade1

Cidade1

Cidade3
```

Gostaria que o DropDownList recebesse somente `Cidade1`, `Cidade2` e `Cidade3` sem repetição.

Na Controller estou usando a seguinte instrução, mas não obtive sucesso:

```
List<Empresa> items = db.Empresa.OrderBy(x => x.Cidade).ThenBy(x => x.Cidade).ToList();
```

Comment: Seria algo como um `distinct campo` na consulta?

Comment: Viu o problema é que no DropDownList esta vindo valores repetidos, tem como você me passar a instrução Distinct ? pois assim esta errado a síntese List<Empresa> items = db.Empresa.OrderBy(x => x.Cidade).Distinct(x => x.Cidade).ToList();

Comment: Se vc quiser algo mais completo, existe [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) mantida pelo Jon Skeet :D Lá você vai encontrar uma versão melhorada do método `Distinct()` que é o `DistinctBy()` ele permite retornar os objetos ao invés de valores únicos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de evitar repetição de valores de um determinado campo é usar o método `Distinct()`, veja um exemplo reproduzível:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class Endereco
    {
        public string Cidade { get;set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Endereco> enderecos = new List<Endereco>
        {
            new Endereco {Cidade = "Cidade1"},
            new Endereco {Cidade = "Cidade2"},
            new Endereco {Cidade = "Cidade3"},
            new Endereco {Cidade = "Cidade1"},
            new Endereco {Cidade = "Cidade4"},
        };

        var enderecosDistinct = enderecos.Select(x => x.Cidade).Distinct();

        enderecosDistinct.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c));
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Cidade1
>   Cidade2
>   Cidade3
>   Cidade4

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0pDSRB).

Mais informações nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10255134/5429980).

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz desta maneira, o que não fugiu às dicas fornecidas no fórum @gato @Ronivaldo Roner

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.cidade= new SelectList(db.Empresa.Select(a => a.Cidade).Distinct());
            return View();
        }

@Html.DropDownList("cidade", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o `.Distinct()`, acredito que irá resolver seu problema.